# FLAG_DIM_BEHIND causing lag on android oreo

Tags: java, android, service, flags

**What I am doing:**

I'm trying to create a simple screen filter (Dimmer) application.

**How I did it:**

I made a service and used the following code to draw over apps.

```
    @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        LAYOUT_FLAG = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY;
    } else {
        LAYOUT_FLAG = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY;
    }


    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_CONTENT,
            LAYOUT_FLAG, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    params.alpha = 0.1f;
    params.dimAmount = 0.41f;

    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    mOverlayView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.filter_layout, null);

    wm.addView(mOverlayView, params);
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

**Problem:**

When i use FLAG_DIM_BEHIND, it causes lags which is clearly visible in opening apps animation.

**What i tried:**

1. Used flags such as FLAG_FULLSCREEN, FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN etc.(Didn't worked)
2. Removed FLAG_DIM_BEHIND and tried to set the color myself using this line:`mOverlayView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.light_black));`

it works well and there isn't any lag but the thing is, it (Screen Filter layout) doesn't cover the whole screen. Navigation Bar stays uncovered. 
Is there anyway to achieve this without lag?

Also, There is an [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eliseo.nightmode) in PlayStore which is doing this without any lag or issue.

**Phone and OS:**

Nexus 6P (8.1 Oreo)

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: That app you linked targets API 23, meaning it doesn't need to use TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY. FLAG_NOT_TOUCABLE combined with TYPE_PHONE meant apps could display over all elements of the screen. This was blocked in Oreo.

Comment: Hey @TheWanderer, Thanks for the reply! I got your point and just changed my target to API 23 as well. Used TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY but the problem still remains. The app i linked is working absolutely fine on Oreo 8.1 though.

Comment: It was blocked if your app is targeting Oreo. I believe you need to use TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT. Either way, you won't be able to publish the app on the Play Store unless you're targeting at least API 26.

Comment: It is not targeting Oreo now. I changed it to API 23 as i mentioned before. Also,  I'm gonna use it personally.